# In Xcode, code that works in Playground does not execute properly in the CommandLineTool project

Tags: swift, xcode, http

I wrote a simple code that makes a GET request to the githubAPI as shown below.

```
import Foundation

let url = URL(string: "https://api.github.com/users/(伏字)")!
let get = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url,completionHandler: { data, response,error in
if let error = error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
    return
}

guard let data = data,
      let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse else {
    print("data or response is nil")
    return
}

if response.statusCode == 200 {
    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8))
} else {
    print("statusCode: \(response.statusCode)")
}
}
)

get.resume()
```

When this code is executed in Playground, the value successfully obtained is returned, but when CommandLineTool is selected when creating a Project, it is executed without error but returns no value. (Even if it is not able to GET, something should be Printed, but it only shows "program ended with exit code: 0".) Solution please.

Is there something I have to do only when I choose CommandLineTool???

Xcode 13.3

macOS 12.3.1

Comment: I think that the program exit before the task ends. You should try using the async version with await

Comment: thanks for advise!
And I'm sorry that I mistook Storyboard for playground..

Comment: Also using async / await is not trivial with the command line script. I suggest following a tutorial if this is your first time doing so.